# gst-launch with tcpserversink not working

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

I am trying to user gst-launch to stream mp3 audio over tcp, this is what I am trying :

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="/path/to/file.mp3" ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=3000
```

but it doesn't work the output is as follow :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPServerSink:tcpserversink0: Internal GStreamer error: negotiation problem.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstmultifdsink.c(2700): gst_multi_fd_sink_render (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPServerSink:tcpserversink0:
Received first buffer without caps set
Execution ended after 94657 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ..
```

Whats the problem where I am going wrong?

I did lots of search on internet but didn't found the right document how to use gst-launch properly. if anyone can please point me to right doc or tell me how to use it it will great.

Answer (score 1):

`tcpserversink` complains about missing caps on its sink pad:

```
Received first buffer without caps set
```

This is because tcpserversink wants to know what it sends.
One way to tell it would be to manually decode and re-encode the stream:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="/path/to/file.mp3" ! mad ! audioconvert ! lame ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=3000
```

But that's just waste of CPU power.
There's an element called `mpegaudioparse` that (apart from some other stuff) figures out the details of the mpeg stream and sets its output caps accordingly. By simply putting it between your `filesrc` and the `tcpserversink` you'll end up with a working pipeline:

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="/path/to/file.mp3" ! mpegaudioparse ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=3000
```